# beginner with Swift with an error UIPicker

Tags: swift, uipicker

I am building a simple app that has a PickerView with 3 selections that should link to 3 viewControllers each named FirstViewController, SecondViewController and ThirdViewController.
But I am getting this error

```
> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Scroller.ViewController: 0x7ff7b5e0b670>) has no segue with identifier 'SecondSegue'
```

I have three options in the picker and a button to go to that selection's viewController:

[image]

My code below works on first loading then crashes

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(chosenState)Segue", sender: nil)
        print("no chance")
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData = ["First","Second","Third"]
    var chosenState = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     print("Help")
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // The number of columns of data


    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    //Called when the user changes the selection...
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        chosenState = pickerData[row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

can anyone help me understand how to fix this ?

Have I named the Segues ok? They are all named the same - is that correct?

Comment: Hi Boober Bunz
Hmm I’m missing something and I can’t stop what you are saying can you give me a little more help regards Jeremy

Comment: " They are all named the same - is that correct?" No. According to your code they should be named `FirstSegue`, `SecondSegue" and `ThirdSegue`.

Comment: Please **read** the error message. It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the segue identifier to second view controller as **SecondSegue**

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `SecondSegue` to your second `UIViewController` has not been named properly.

Be careful, it is case sensitive, it must be named precisely `SecondSegue`. And after having changed the name, don't forget to validate your input with the return key.